# Python PCAP question function definition issue

Tags: python, function, lambda

I am studying for the PCAP and I have a practice test from them, and one of the questions makes no sense to me, let alone how they got the answer. There have been some typos in the test, so maybe this is a typo, but I don't see how this is valid in any way... The question and possible answers verbatim:

What is the expected output of the following code?

```
def f(1):
    return 1 (-3, 3)

print(f(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y))

ANSWER OPTIONS:

A. 3
B. 0
C. -3
D. None
```

I answered None because I didn't think you could define a function that way with a literal integer as the parameter. I understand what's going on with the lambda function and its logic, I just do not understand the function definition and the logic of getting the answer that the Python Institute PCAP practice test says is A., 3

If anyone can explain the definition and how it works or definitively say 'That has to be a typo' I would be much obliged.

Comment: Are you sure it's a numeral `1` and not a lowercase `L`  or `I` ?

Comment: That is a great suggestion and I think you are right. I have been staring at these questions for too long. Still a little miffed as how the return statement works tho, returning lowercase 'l' for our purposes and then that ordered pair, (-3, 3). Is it always going to return that same ordered pair regardless of what letter I pass as a parameter?

Comment: It's not returning `l` and `(-3, 3)`, but `l(-3, 3)`. `l` is a function.

Answer (score 2):

The argument 1 here and the 1 in the return are most likely a lowercase L. If you are using some online practice dump for the exam, beware that a lot of them contain a lot of errors.

With lowercase L as the argument, the code will run fine...

```
def f(l):
    return l (-3, 3)

print(f(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y))
```

...and print 3 indeed.

Comment: Thanks! This is the actual Python Institute practice material stuff. I just misread it.